# Error "Parameter not valid" create chart with two series

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm getting an error while trying to create a chart with a macro in excel this is what I'm trying

```
Dim mychart As Chart
Set mychart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmooth).Chart

Dim objCht As ChartObject
Dim Tplot As Range ' T in x axis
Dim Pplot As Range ' P in y axis

Set objCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)

Set Tplot = Range("W8:W" & Tendcell)
Set Pplot = Range("X8:X" & Tendcell)
Set Zplot = Range("Y8:Y" & Tendcell)
With objCht.Chart
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Tplot
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Pplot
    .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Tplot
    .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Zplot


End With
```

I'm getting an error: parameter not valid

How can I specify the series that the data belongs to ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the series first before trying to set the values. Also, use `Option Explicit` at the top to check you variable declarations. You had a few missing including that you didn't declare/define `TendCell` so I have just set it to 12.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim mychart As Chart
    Set mychart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmooth).Chart

    Dim objCht As ChartObject
    Dim Tplot As Range                           ' T in x axis
    Dim Pplot As Range                           ' P in y axis
    Dim Zplot As Range

    Set objCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)

    Dim TendCell As Long
    TendCell = 12

    With ActiveSheet
        Set Tplot = .Range("W8:W" & TendCell)
        Set Pplot = .Range("X8:X" & TendCell)
        Set Zplot = .Range("Y8:Y" & TendCell)
    End With

    With objCht.Chart

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Tplot
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Pplot
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Tplot
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Zplot


    End With

End Sub
```