# Getting x axis value from Excel chart in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to get the x axis value when you click on an Excel chart.

Perusing Stack Overflow I've found some viable code but there's one last bug I don't understand...

```
Private Sub Chart_MouseUp _
        (ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)
    
    Dim ElementID As Long, Arg1 As Long, Arg2 As Long
    Dim myX As Double, myY As Double
    
    With ActiveChart
        .GetChartElement X, Y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2
        
        Application.StatusBar = "[" & ElementID & "]"
        
        If ElementID = xlSeries Or ElementID = xlDataLabel Then
            If Arg2 > 0 Then
                myX = WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues, Arg2)
                myY = WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Values, Arg2)
                
                MsgBox "Series " & Arg1 & vbCrLf _
                       & """" & .SeriesCollection(Arg1).Name & """" & vbCrLf _
                       & "Point " & Arg2 & vbCrLf _
                       & "X = " & myX & vbCrLf _
                       & "Y = " & myY & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                       & "Any questions?"
            End If
        End If
        
    End With
End Sub
```

It gets stuck at

```
myX = WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues, Arg2)
```

It says runtime error 1004 - parameter not valid.

Any clues appreciated!

Comment: I'm not able to get the error from your code.  What kind of chart are you using - can you give a little more info on that?  (I was experimenting with a scatter plot that had one small data series.)  Also, why do you use `WorksheetFunction.Index(.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues, Arg2)` instead of `.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues(Arg2)`?

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001228/error-parameter-not-valid-create-chart-with-two-series) that had a similar problem.  I believe your issue is that `Arg1` is occasionally larger than the the number of series in the series collection.  Therefore, `.SeriesCollection(Arg1)` doesn't exist, and you get the "parameter not found error".

Although I'm not sure why this is happening, you could probably get around this by adding a check to your if statement.  Something like `If Arg2 > 0 And Arg1 <= .SeriesCollection.Count Then`.